# Will I get an error if I use new keyword which creating objects of structs?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```js
struct Foo {
string foo1;
}

Foo foo = new Foo("foo");
```

Will I get an error if I run this code?

Comment: You can check it on your own. Use [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/)

Comment: Why can't you run it yourself to find out? It would be much faster than it took you to write this question here, and you might learn something in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannnot use the `new` keyword for creating structs.

If you're creating the struct inside a function, you also need to define its data location (`memory` in the example below), as `struct` is a [reference type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#reference-types).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct Foo {
        string foo1;
    }

    // implicit `storage` location of the property
    Foo foo1 = Foo("foo");

    function myFunction() public {
        // need to explicitly state location of the variable
        Foo memory foo2 = Foo("foo"); 
    }
}
```